# Authentication using Spinnaker expression helper function

Tags: spinnaker

I have built a pipeline that is triggered by a Git push on a specific file which contains additional meta information like the target namespace and version of the kubernetes manifest to be deployed.
Within an expression I would like to read the artifact using

```
${ #fromUrl( execution['trigger']['resolvedExpectedArtifacts'][0]['boundArtifact']['reference'] ) }
```

What I try to achieve is a GitOps approach with a set of config files in Git which trigger a pipeline for a parameterized Kubernetes manifest to deploy multiple resources.

When I execute that expression either by starting the pipeline or using `curl` I get 401 (in orca logs). The Git credentials are configured using username/password and token as well in config as in orca-local.yml.
But it seems they are not used.

Am I on the wrong path, is there an easier way to access a file's content in a pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That helper won't go through any sort of authentication, it will expect the endpoint to be open to your spinnaker instance.

Spinnaker normally treats artifacts as pass-through, so in order to get the contents of the file inside the pipeline you'll have to go through an intermediate stage such as writing out a property file in a jenkins stage ( https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/expressions/#property-files ) or via webhook with custom auth headers.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have learned that by looking into the code. Will keep up with Spinnaker probably for the next couple of months, maybe reporting issues or providing fixes.